# How could I change the name of my Yarn Workspace package?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I starting with a yarn workspace that has packages that are already named. I'd like to change the name of one of the packages but have not been able to find the necessary procedure for doing this.

Here's the current structure of the file:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-theme-workspace",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn workspace example build"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "gatsby-theme-minimal",
    "example"
  ]
}
```

The workspace name that I'd like to change is `gatsby-theme-minimal`, I'd also like to know how I'd change the other one `example` when that becomes necessary, so advice on that would also be appreciated. I appreciate that this is probably a simple process but I am as yet unaware of how it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two concepts that is used in your question.

1. The directory name of the workspace. To change it just rename the directory and update `workspaces` field to refer to the new directory name
2. The package name of the workspace - it is provided in `package.json` inside `name` field for the corresponding workspace. For `gatsby-theme-minimal` it is provided inside `gatsby-theme-minimal/package.json` -> `name`. Just edit `package.json` and change the name.

After making changes via 1) or 2) or both of them you need to run `yarn` in order for Yarn to update any installation files that refer to them. If you change workspace package name as per 2) you should also edit and update any code that requires/imports workspace by the old package name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Viktor. It is along the lines of what I had been thinking but wanted to confirm in case I edited and caused errors all over the place. Thanks very much for the clarification :).

Comment: Great answer, since it is not clear from the docs, without actually testing it out.

Comment: If you are renaming a workspace (point 2) that other workspaces depend on, it’s not enough to simply update the name in that workspace’s package.json; `getWorkspaceByDescriptor` will throw when you run `yarn`. You must also update all those other workspaces’ dependencies to use the new name for the workspace in question.